# Regex to delete emojis from string

Tags: regex, unicode, sed, emoji

I have a [list of the Unicode emojis](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-test.txt) and I want to strip the emojis from them (i.e just want the whole first part and the name at the end of the row). A sample rows are like these ones:

```
1F468 1F3FD 200D 2695 FE0F   ; fully-qualified # ‍⚕️ man health worker: medium skin tone
1F469 1F3FF 200D 2695        ; non-fully-qualified # ‍⚕ woman health worker: dark skin tone
```

(from where I have deleted some spaces for the sake of simplicity). What I want is to match is the `[non-]fully-qualified` part as well as the `#` and the emoji, so I can delete them with `sed`. I have tried the following regex

```
 sed -e 's/\<[on-]*fully-qualified\># *.+?(?=[a-zA-Z]) //g'
```

which tries to match the words `[non-]fully-qualified` a space, the `#` symbol, and then whatever you can find (non-greedy) until the first letter, and replace it with an empty string.

I would like to have this output:

```
1F468 1F3FD 200D 2695 FE0F   ; man health worker: medium skin tone
1F469 1F3FF 200D 2695        ; woman health worker: dark skin tone
```

I have tried several posted answers to no avail, and besides, I'm trying to match a pattern between two boundaries which is were I'm having the trouble

EDIT: I'm trying to run the command in the git bash shipped with git for windows

Comment: Would this work for you? `sed 's/\(.*;\).*#[^a-zA-Z]*\(.*\)/\1 \2/'`

Comment: Your sed script appears to be trying to use a PCRE but no version of sed supports PCREs. Which sed version are you running through - GNU or OSX or something else?

Comment: @archimiro seems to be doing something, but doesn't delete the whole thing in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not pretty sure, but this might work:

```
sed 's/;.*fully-qualified\s*#[^a-zA-Z]*/; /'
```

This will replace anything that is a semicolon `;`, followed by any character `.*`, followed by the "fully-qualified" text, followed by any number of spaces, followed by a hashtag, followed by any character that is **not** a-zA-Z `[^a-zA-Z]`, and replace all that with a semicolon followed by a space.

To be sure that the `[a-zA-Z]` captures only *a to z* and *A to Z* without any other characters, which seems to be the problem, a quick fix just for that command could be to use `LC_ALL=C`:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/;.*fully-qualified\s*#[^a-zA-Z]*/; /' file
```

Comment: Nope, the output is the same as posted in my third comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45783849/5477531)

Comment: @c4tich Seems like a windows issue, you can try running sed with `LC_ALL=C sed ...`, for example: `LC_ALL=C sed 's/;.*fully-qualified *#[^a-zA-Z]*/; /'`

Comment: This did the trick! Care to explain why? also, I can't understand the last semicolon in the regex... (_why_ does [a-zA-Z] match other things besides [a-zA-Z]?)

Comment: Looked up LC_ALL, found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do It appears that LC_ALL forces it to treat the input as simple ASCII instead of doing whatever Windows was doing to muck up the encoding and throw the regexes off. Seems like a handy thing to know for the future. Thanks @archimiro

Comment: Updated the answer, English if not my first language and I'm not very fluent, sorry for any grammar or spelling mistake, hope the explanation is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I like to search for what I actually *want* and then keep it.

This works on OS X in my testing:

`sed -E 's/^([^#]+)#[^a-zA-Z\s]*(.*)$/\1 # \2/g'`

EDIT: I don't have the Windows version of `sed` to try, but maybe this will work. Not as precise, but short and simple.

`sed -e 's/#\s*[^a-zA-Z\s]*/# /g'`

EDIT AGAIN: My bad, I read the question again and you wanted to delete more than just the emoji. This one should do it.

`sed -e 's/;[^#]*#\s*[^a-zA-Z\s]*/; /g'`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Similar output to that of the @argimiro's command

Comment: What's the output, and what's the difference from what you're expecting? What does the second command turn the example input data from your question into on your machine?

Comment: Still the same as the previous one. This is the output: `1F468 1F3FD 200D 2695 FE0F                 ; <A8><U+200D>⚕️ man health worker: medium skin tone` I think it strips something because you can see that you don't get the full emoji here

Comment: That is a weird result. Maybe some disagreement about encoding is causing the Windows version to have a different idea of what constitutes whitespace. Let's try it searching for literal spaces only: `sed -e 's/;[^#]*# *[^a-zA-Z ]*/; /g'`

Comment: Nope, same output.

Comment: Is the source file's encoding in something other than UTF-8?

Comment: No, I opened the file in atom and it says UTF-8

Comment: Your copy of sed seems broken to me :-/ It's as if it's choking when it runs into non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152392/discussion-between-c4tich-and-charles-srstka).